# .NET Core and angular app proxy.conf.js not workling

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have some Angular code which I want to call a .NET Core controller.

Angular 17.2 code:

```
getBooking() {
    this.http.get<Booking>('/api/bookings/289745675').subscribe(
      (result) => {
        //   this. Booking = result;
      },
      (error) => {
        console. Error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

To the console is written an error but the message reports a 200 http code!

I've tried:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
 {
    context: [
      "/api/*"
    ],
    target,
    secure: false
  }
]

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
  "/api/*": {
    "target",
    "secure": false
  }
}
]
```

I've set the url to `/api/bookings/289745675` and every other combination!

It never hits my .NET Core 8.0 controller which looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Server.Data.Models;

namespace Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/bookings")]
    public class BookingController : ControllerBase
    {
        protected Data.BookingsService _bookingsService { get; set; }

        private readonly ILogger<BookingController> _logger;

        public BookingController(Data.BookingsService BookingsService, ILogger<BookingController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _bookingsService = BookingsService;
        }

        [HttpGet("{apiRef}")]
        public async Task<BookingDetails> Get(int apiRef)
        {
            var booking = await _bookingsService.GetBookingDetails(Guid.Parse("0230c690-542c-488b-a8d5-34a32589c982"), apiRef);
            return booking;
        }
    }
}
```

Making a curl request to:

port 4200 is the Angular app

```
curl get https://localhost:4200/api/bookings/289745675
```

This gets routed to the angular app rather than hitting the controller!! The proxy settings aren't working!

port 7005 is the .NET core

```
curl get https://localhost:7005/api/bookings/289745675
```

This gets routed to the controller as expected!

Wits end!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide the error message please. Also information about the request from the devtools network tab might help.